# stop function from affecting an element after it was moved to another element

Tags: jquery, html

So I have to html lists - one to select from, other to add to.

```
<ul id="selet_from">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="add_to">

</ul>
```

When I click on item in "select from" list I need to add some text and move it "add to" list.

```
function add_to_selected(){
    $('#selet_from li:not(#add_to li)').click(function(){
        //need to add text in child element for easy removal - works
        $(this).html('<span>adittional text - </span>'+$(this).html());

        // move element to 'selected' list
        $(this).appendTo('#add_to');

        // initialize remove from list on newly added items
        remove_from_selected();

        console.log('add')
    });
};
```

everything works fine so far.

If by accident I added wrond item to "add to" list then i should be able to reverse the action simply by clicking on it. Meaning, click on item in "add to" list should remove previously added text and move item back to "select from" list

```
function remove_from_selected(){
    $('#add_to li').click(function(){
        // need to remove <span child>
        // example below doesn't work :(
        $(this).remove('span');

        // need to take element back to #selet_from
        $(this).appendTo('#selet_from');

        console.log('remove')
    });
};

add_to_selected();
```

The problem is that `add_to_selected()` function should not be executed after element was moved to "add to" list and vice versa. http://jsfiddle.net/DpBbZ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for dynamic evaluation of the selectors, use delegated event handling

```
$('#selet_from').on('click', 'li', function () {
    //need to add text in child element for easy removal - works
    $(this).html('<span>adittional text - </span>' + $(this).html());

    // move element to 'selected' list
    $(this).appendTo('#add_to');
});


$('#add_to').on('click', 'li', function () {
    // need to remove <span child>
    // example below doesn't work :(
    $(this).children().remove();

    // need to take element back to #selet_from
    $(this).appendTo('#selet_from');

    console.log('remove')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pA9RR/)

Comment: Ohh, I see instead of directly adding method to objects you want to manipulate, you add methods to their containers. wow, thanks!